# На сцене не выполняются действия при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, javafx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
в этом коде не работают кнопки, почему- то они нажимаются, но ничего не происходит, хотя я прописывал, что если нажмут на кнопку

```
package application;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class signUpCont {

    @FXML
    private TextField rgL;

    @FXML
    private TextField rgP;


    @FXML
    private Button rgButton;

    @FXML
    private ProgressIndicator lo;
    @FXML
    private Button vixod22;
    void initialize() {
        vixod22.setOnAction(event ->{
            vixod22.getScene().getWindow().hide();
            FXMLLoader loader3 = new FXMLLoader();
            loader3.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/application/viskas.fxml"));
            try {
                loader3.load();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Parent rooting13 = loader3.getRoot();
            Stage stage13 = new Stage();
            stage13.setScene(new Scene(rooting13));
            stage13.setResizable(false);
            stage13.showAndWait();


        });
        rgButton.setOnAction(event ->{
            System.out.print("adadada");
            String loginnText = rgL.getText().trim();
            String passwordText = rgP.getText().trim();
            int long1= loginnText.length();
            int password1 = passwordText.length();
            if(password1<5) {rgL.setText("Пароль должен состоять минимум из 5 символов");}
            if(long1<6) {rgP.setText("Логин должен состоять минимум из 6 символов");}
            if(long1>=6 && password1>=5) {
            Databases dbHandler = new Databases();
            User user2 = new User();


            user2.setLogin(loginnText);


            dbHandler.getUser(user2);
            ResultSet result = dbHandler.getUber(user2);
            int counter =  0;// должно быть значение 0, но т.к хостинг для датабаз платный, то я поставил значение 1, чтобы вы могли пройти дальше,p.s  я нашел бесплатный хостинг, поэтому значение 0
            try{while(result.next()) {
                counter++;}}catch(SQLException e1){e1.printStackTrace();}
            if(counter >=1) {UIManager.put("OptionPane.messageForeground", Color.WHITE);
             UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", Color.DARK_GRAY);
             UIManager.put("Panel.background", Color.DARK_GRAY);UIManager.put("Button.background", Color.GRAY);JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Такой пользователь уже зарегестрирован", "MineLauncher", counter, null);}else {dbHandler.SingUpUser(null,rgL.getText(), rgP.getText());}
        if(counter <1) {UIManager.put("OptionPane.messageForeground", Color.WHITE);
         UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", Color.DARK_GRAY);
         UIManager.put("Panel.background", Color.DARK_GRAY);UIManager.put("Button.background", Color.GRAY);JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Поздравляю, вы зарегестрировались!" );}

            }
        });
    };

}
```

хмпль файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane opacity="0.57" prefHeight="258.0" prefWidth="575.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FF4500;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="signUpCont">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="225.0" prefWidth="596.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FDF5E6;">
         <children>
            <MenuBar layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="-2.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="589.0">
              <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Fiel">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
              </menus>
            </MenuBar>
            <TextField fx:id="rgL" layoutX="233.0" layoutY="57.0" promptText="Ваш будующий логин" />
            <TextField fx:id="rgP" layoutX="233.0" layoutY="100.0" promptText="Ваш будующий пароль" />
            <Button fx:id="rgButton" layoutX="253.0" layoutY="137.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="110.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 50;" text="регистрация">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Bookman Old Style" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <ProgressIndicator fx:id="lo" layoutX="295.0" layoutY="170.0" progress="0.0" />
            <Button fx:id="vixod22" layoutX="348.0" layoutY="178.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-radius: 12;" text="Выход" />
         </children></AnchorPane>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="206.0" layoutY="222.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="186.0" text="MineLauncher">
         <font>
            <Font name="Berlin Sans FB" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="3.0" layoutY="241.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="by Gokor8" textFill="#6b4f4f" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: а что должно произойти по факту?

Comment: на одной кнопке, должна смениться сцена, на другой, отправить данные в базу данных, ноь по факту, кнопки просто кликаются, а действий нету

Comment: у Вас fxml файл (который хмпль) видит контроллер? В классе контроллере слева от ` @FXML` появился значек fxml файла?

Comment: да, выделилось все цветом, мб баг?  и переделать сцену?

Comment: т.к дже размер странно регулируется через scene builder

Comment: приложи плиз скрин контроллера, где у тебя аннотации FXML прописаны

Comment: я изменил вопрос, добавив скрин

Comment: эх, я почему-то был уверен, что ты работаешь через IntelliJ IDEA, смысл такой, мне кажется у тебя FXML файл не связан с контроллером `signUpCont`, они не видят друг-друга, иначе хоть что-то бы, да происходило, для начала пиши имена класса всегда с заглавной буквы, это правило (с fxml файлами можно так не делать), проверь еще раз все имена, убедись, что контроллер связан с fxml

Comment: @VladZherihov, в AnchorPane верхнего уровня контроллер прописан. Связь обработчиков с кнопками в самом коде прописана, не в fxml.

Comment: @AXMEDJAN, у вас перехватываются исключения в обработчиках нажатия, возможно происходит какая-то ошибка, она куда-то выводится через `e.printStackTrace()`, но вы ее не видите, и кажется что ничего не происходит.

Comment: скоере всего так, тюк я все связывал + не было бы связи вылетела бы ошибка, а так у меня все связанно, но ошибок нету в консоли

Comment: ладно, я создала новую сцену, в которой все работает, так было бы легче

Comment: Предположу, что не хватало аннотации `@FXML` перед методом `initialize()`.

Comment: я еблан facepulm